# How to calculate Rotation Matrix in android from accelerometer and magnetometer sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, magnetometer

I found the rotation matrix returned by SensorManager.getRotationMatrix from link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381649/whats-the-best-3d-angular-co-ordinate-system-for-working-with-smartphone-apps/382048#382048
The rotation matrix is:
[image: Rotation matrix returned from getRotationMatrix]

But I cannot find the steps to reconstruct this matrix when I used the rotation matrix for each axis as specified in link: http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf

[image: Rotation matrix for each axis]

I really appreciate if anyone can show me the steps so that I can construct the above rotation matrix because I cannot find any document that shows me the steps to create this matrix.

And at the above link, there is also a matrix as following:
[image: Rotation matrix for compass]

How can I calculate the matrix [image: Matrix for plane EN]. What does it mean?

Comment: I believe you have already gone through the following wikipedia article ... if not yet please see if this may serve as a pointer to the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: What is it you are trying to solve? What would you like to do with the rotation matrix? Looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157577).

Comment: The above matrix is used to calculate to Euler angles in method SensorManager.getOrientation(). I just tried to understand the math applied to the rotation matrix in Android because it's different from the other rotation matrices I could find and I cannot figure out the steps to construct the above rotation matrix. Understanding the algorithm helps me write the mathematical formula when I only need some values in matrix, instead of calculating the whole rotation matrix. Values of sensors are changed in high rate and complex math would consume many CPU resources and battery power.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it!

Your general rotation matrix R can be constructed from the axis-specific rotation matrices R_x, R_y, R_z!

The axis-specific rotation matrices rotate around each of the major axes. If you combine them, you'll get the general rotation matrix R you are looking for.

So:

R = R_x * R_y * R_z.